# url not loading in webview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview

I want to open an URL in UiWebView

In my ios 5.1 and 6.0 simulator following code is working fine but in my ios 4.3 real device it is not working.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
    NSLog(@"url=%@",url);
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

what is missing in my code?

Comment: what strWebsiteUrl contains? Please post actual string.

Comment: did you delegate your webview from xib?

Comment: where you have included this snippet? Did you outlet webview with xib?

Comment: When you say "not working", what are the symptoms?  Do you have a delegate with a `webView:didFailLoadWithError:` method?

Comment: yes control goes to webView:didFailLoadWithError: this method

Comment: Perhaps posting the error would help people to help you....

Answer (score 0):

Please use this:

```
  webView.delegate = self;
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]; 
  NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]; 
  [webView setScalesPageToFit:YES];         
  [webView loadRequest:request];
```

add this new method in your class

```
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{
   NSLog("Error : %@",error);
}
```

Hope it works for you. If there is some other issue, like connection, then you will see it in Log.

Thanks